# Determining compactness and completeness of metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness, complete-spaces

> Metric Space: *(M,d)*

**Set:**

$M =  \{   (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:y>0 $ or $   x=0=y    \}$

**Metric:**

$d((x,y),(a,b)) = $min$\{ $max$  \{  |x-a|,|y-b| \},y+b  \}$

$\space$

**completeness:**

$\lim_{n \to \infty}(1,\frac{1}{n}) = (1,0)$ which does not exist in the set, hence the metric space is not complete

**compactness:**

The sequence $a_n = (n,n)$ contains no subsequence which converges in $M$. Hence the space is not compact.

$\space$

Are my answers correct? If so, what was the purpose of the distance function? If not, where am I going wrong? Thanks for any answers.

Comment: $a_n = n$ is not a sequence in this set.

Comment: Is $a_n = (n,n)$ correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful! In the *usual* metric, we do indeed have that $(1,\frac1n)$ converges to $(1,0),$ but we aren't *using* the usual metric. In fact, the sequence *does* converge in this space, to the point $(0,0)$! In fact, given *any* sequence of points of $M$ that we would expect to converge somewhere on the $x$-axis, it will converge to $(0,0)$ in $\langle M,d\rangle.$ This is even true of sequences that approach the $x$-axis that we *wouldn't* expect to converge, like $$v_n:=\left(n,2^{-n}\right).$$ Aside from that, convergence behaves the way we'd expect it to. Hence, the space *is* complete!

To prove it, take any Cauchy sequence. If the sequence is bounded away from the $x$-axis--that is, if the second components don't converge to $0$--then you can show that the sequence converges where we'd expect it to converge. Otherwise, you can show that the sequence converges to $(0,0),$ despite our expectations.

Your approach to prove it isn't compact is a good one, but you still have to show that no subsequence can converge. Probably the simplest approach is to show that no subsequence is Cauchy.

---

**Added**: Let me expand on my answer, since this metric has some strangely-shaped open "balls." Let's denote and define the open "ball" with "radius" $r$ and "center" $(h,k)$ by $$B_r(h,k):=\Bigl\{(x,y)\in M:d\bigl((x,y),(h,k)\bigr)<r\Bigr\}.$$

---

First, let's consider the open "balls" that are "centered" at $(0,0).$ Note that $$d\bigl((x,y),(0,0)\bigr)=\min\Bigl\{\max\bigl\{|x-0|,|y-0|\bigr\},y+0\Bigr\}=\min\Bigl\{\max\bigl\{|x|,y\bigr\},y\Bigr\}.$$ Note that if $|x|<y,$ then $$d\bigl((x,y),(0,0)\bigr)=\min\{y,y\}=y,$$ and if $y\le|x|,$ then $$d\bigl((x,y),(0,0)\bigr)=\min\bigl\{|x|,y\bigr\}=y.$$ Hence, for all $r>0$ we have $$B_r(0,0)=\bigl\{(x,y)\in M:y<r\bigr\}.$$ Consequently, given any sequence of points $(x_n,y_n)\in M$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=0,$ we have that $\lim_{n\to\infty}d\bigl((x_n,y_n),(0,0)\bigr)=0.$ That is, any such sequence converges to $(0,0)$ in $\langle M,d\rangle.$

---

Now let's consider what happens when $(h,k)\ne(0,0).$ Note in particular that this means $k>0,$ given the definition of $M.$

First, let's consider the (relatively) simple case that $0<r\le k.$ Note that $d\bigl((x,y),(h,k)\bigr)<r$ if and only if $\max\bigl\{|x-h|,|y-k|\bigr\}<r$ or $y+k<r.$ (Do you see why?) But $y\ge0$ and $r\le k,$ so $y+k<r$ isn't possible! Thus, $d\bigl((x,y),(h,k)\bigr)<r$ if and only if $\max\bigl\{|x-h|,|y-k|\bigr\}<r,$ which occurs if and only if $|x-h|<r$ and $|y-k|<r.$ (Do you see why?) Thus, $B_r(h,k)$ is the interior of the square with vertices $(h\pm r,k+r)$ and $(h\pm r,k-r),$ in the case that $0<r\le k.$

But what if $r>k$? Well, one can show that $$B_r(h,k)=\bigl\{(0,0)\bigr\}\cup\bigl\{(x,y)\in M:0<y<r-k\bigr\}\cup\bigl\{(x,y)\in M:h-r<x<h+r\text{ and }r-k\le y<k+r\bigr\}.$$ What a mess! For example, [here is the rough shape](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3E0+and+min%28y%2B2%2C+max%28%7Cx-1%7C%2C%7Cy-2%7C%29%29%3C5) of the open "ball" of "radius" $5$ with "center" $(1,2).$ Fortunately, as far as convergence is concerned, this doesn't really matter! We can restrict ourselves to the case that $0<r\le k$ to show that, given a sequence of points $(x_n,y_n)\in M$ and a point $(h,k)\in M$ with $k\ne 0,$ we have that the sequence converges to $(h,k)$ in $\langle M,d\rangle$ if and only if it converges to $(h,k)$ in the usual metric.

Comment: I believe the following is true: Let $X$ be a metrizable space. If every metric on $X$ is complete then $X$ is compact. So for a noncompact metric space clearly you must pay attention to the specific metric!

Comment: "In fact, given any sequence of points of $M$ that we would expect to converge somewhere on the $x$-axis, it will converge to $(0,0)$ in $⟨M,d⟩$." Could you demonstrate this in more detail. I can't seem to figure it out for myself, I'm very new to metric spaces.

Comment: The kicker is to use the fact that for any $(x,y)\in M,$ we have $$0\leq d\bigl((x,y),(0,0)\bigr)\leq y+0=y.$$ Now consider any sequence of points $(x_n,y_n)$ in $M$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=0.$

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, I think I've successfully proved that. Now I'm stuck at this: "if the second components don't converge to 0 then you can show that the sequence converges where we'd expect it to converge." This is a very tricky one, and given this metric it doesn't seem intuitive to me. Also, since all subsets of $R^n$ which are bounded are totally bounded, can't we simply show that $M$ is not bounded, and hence is not totally bounded and not compact?

Comment: @Gregory: I will expand my answer to address the convergence. As for boundedness, since compact implies totally bounded, which in turn imples bounded, then it does suffice to show that $M$ isn't an open $d$-ball of finite radius. Still, I think your first approach is better, since you'll need a pretty good handle on the metric for a boundedness proof.

Comment: @Gregory: Hopefully, my expanded answer will make it easier for you to prove noncompactness (whatever approach you take), as well as completeness. Let me know if you've any more questions.

Comment: Yes, one final question (and thanks for your patience). Given the definition of the ball centred at $(0,0)$ with radius $r$, how can we actually say: as the $y$-value tends to $0$ the entire sequence must tend to $(0,0)$. I can't see the intuition here. Sorry if it should be obvious. i.e - I can't make the connection between the ball and the converging sequences.

Comment: @Gregory: Well, given *any* metric space $\langle M,d\rangle,$ what is the formal definition of sequence convergence in the space? What is your intuitive understanding of the formal definition?

Comment: A sequence converges to $L$, if, given any point along the sequence, there is some $\epsilon$ s.t the distance ($d$) between every subsequent point and $L$ is smaller than $\epsilon$.

Comment: @Gregory: That's not correct, unfortunately. Consider the sequence of real numbers $x_n=(-1)^n.$ While it clearly doesn't converge to $0$ (or anything else, for that matter), putting $\epsilon>2,$ we have that *every* point of the sequence is at a distance from $0$ that is smaller than $2.$ What you have given is a definition of a sequence being *bounded*.

Comment: @Gregory: A sequence $x_n$ of points of $M$ concerges to a point $x\in M$ with respect to a metric $d$ on $M$ if for every $\epsilon>0,$ there is a point $x_N$ along the sequence such that all subsequent points of the sequence are at a $d$-distance less than $\epsilon$ away from $x$--that is, $$d(x_n,x)<\epsilon$$ for all $n>N.$

Comment: @Gregory: Translated into terms of open $d$-balls, $x_n$ converges to $x$ w.r.t. $d$ if for every open $d$-ball centered at $x$ (no matter how small), at most finitely-many points of the sequence lie outside the ball. You should be able to prove the equivalence (it's a good exercise). The intuition in each case is that a sequence converges to a point if we can eventually make all the sequence terms as close as we like to the point, just by going far enough in the sequence.

Comment: @Gregory: So, if we have a sequence of terms $(x_n,y_n)$ such that $y_n$ converges to $0,$ then for any $r>0,$ what can we (eventually) conclude about the sequence terms $(x_n,y_n)$?

Comment: then for any $r>0$ infinitely many points $(x_n, y_n)$ exists in the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $(0,0)$ ? I think.

Comment: @Gregory: That's right! Can you prove it? As a hint: let $\epsilon=r.$